# Counting layer segments in QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, count

I have a segmented line (road) dataset and I want to get the number of times each road is segmented.

In SQL it's just

```sql
SELECT RoadMntnc, count(RoadMntnc) AS count
FROM clip_DSC_Roads
GROUP BY RoadMntnc
```

How do I do the same in field calculator?

Sample data is in https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RL7VZL_giZuZ9xVfDFgk409_RIErIB0m?usp=sharing

I assume it would be something like
`aggregate(count("RoadMntnc"), group_by="RoadMntnc")` but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: or to your changed request it should be:

```
array_length( array_agg( "RoadMntnc", "RoadMntnc"))
```

You can use the following expression to count the segments of a line or polygon:

```py
num_geometries(segments_to_lines($geometry))
```

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks - this works but I didn't explain what I meant by segments properly. I don't mean the number of vertices on the line (each time it bends). What I meant is that a single road is made up of multiple lines with the same road name. I want to get the number of lines that make up a road. The SQL in the question does this...I want to do the same in field calculator. It should be some form of the aggregate/group_by expression but I can't figure it out.

Comment: this should be:   array_length( array_agg( "RoadMntnc", "RoadMntnc"))

Comment: -brilliant. That works well. Good value for money on this question where you have given 2 great answers that will both be helpful. :-)